# Tradeoffs of using Loess regression to fit random walks

Tags: regression, prediction, quants, random-walk

I am curious if anyone has had much experience attempting to predict random walks using Loess regression or a variant of local statistical methods.

Comment: It is used in the fitting of volatility surface (local volatility), so you can find some applications there.

Comment: a pure random walk cannot be predicted any better than simply taking the last value. So statically any other means would increase both bias and variance.